# Update specific database record in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Good day, I have some trouble making an update specific record on a selected row from the database. I want to display the data after clicking on the edit icon from the selected data from the table display table. 
[image]

Controller:

```
//Show Users/Members page
public function users_page() {
  $data['users'] = $this->user->get_users();
  $this->load->view('user_page' , $data);
}
```

Model:

```
// Retrieve user data from database
public function get_users() {
  $this->db->select('id, email, first_name, last_name, date_registered');
  $this->db->from('auth_users');
  $query = $this->db->get();

  $result = $query->result();

foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
// var_dump($key);
$data[$key] = array(
    'id'  => $value->id,
    'firstname' => $value->first_name,
    'lastname' => $value->last_name,
    'datereg' => $value->date_registered,
    'email' => $value->email
    );
}
    return $data;
}
```

View:

```
        <table class="table table-condensed">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Date Registered</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach($users as $key => $value) {?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $value['firstname']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value['lastname']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value['email']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value['datereg']; ?></td>
            <td><a href="<?php echo site_url('main/update/'.$value['id']); ?>"><i class="material-icons" title="Click to update">mode_edit</i></a> |
             <a href="<?php echo site_url('main/delete_row/'.$value['id']); ?>"><i class="material-icons" title="Click to remove">delete</i></a></td>
          </tr>
          <?php } ?>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. create a new method in your **controller**, something like this (not exactly like this as I don't know the classes you're already using)

   ```
   public function show_user($id) {
     $data['users'] = $this->user->get_user($id);
     $this->load->view('user_page' , $data);
   }
   ```
2. create another method in your **model**, again something like this

   ```
   public function get_user($id) {
     $this->db->select('id, email, first_name, last_name, date_registered');
     $this->db->from('auth_users');
     $this->db->where('id', $id); 
     $query = $this->db->get();

     $result = $query->result();
     $var_dump($result); --or write a view an pass the result to the view
   ```
3. create a form taking the result from the previous (This I cannot write for you)
4. create an update method in your **controller** and **model** (just like you just did to query the information, but now to update the information from this record)

Comment: thanks for a quick response. I tried above code and worked but i get Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: you will have only 1 record you want to edit at a time, why do you want to use for each/.

Comment: Thanks I added a foreach() and passed $result as key now it worked fine just want i needed. Thanks

Comment: @zzz No need for that. Since you're expecting one row from db, you can use `$result = $query->row();`. [Docs]( https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#result-rows).